# Django template does not return list of objects from model

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my Django project. I want the template to get objects from the database and list them, but the template does not return objects. My project scripts are as following.

This is my models file:

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.FloatField(default=0.5)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.breed
```

This is my views file:

```
def dog(request):
    context = {

        "dog_list": Dog.objects.all()
    }


    return render(request, 'dog.html', context)
```

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Welcome to Dog sharing platform</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2> Dog types </h2>
    <div>
        <ul>
        {% for x in dog_list %}
            <li>{{x.dog_list}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run server, This page returns a page that shows **Dog types** and **a blank list**

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 1):

`dog_list` is a list of Dog items. Each Dog doesn't have an attribute `dog_list`, though; it has `breed`, `name` etc. So you need to use those attributes:

```
   {% for x in dog_list %}
        <li>{{ x.breed }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
```